# How to fill django MySql db with foreign language content

Tags: mysql, django-admin

I want to fill some of of my django model in django admin and contents are in persian not english

but when I click save button I got this error :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _warning_check
                      warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)


     Exception Value: Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xAF\xD8\xB1\xD9\x85...' for column 'head' at row 1
```

is there any special config need for mysql ?

Comment: You should configure the correct character set.

Answer (score 0):

I got what to do :D

just add following code to my.conf

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```